# How to join two pyspark dataframe based on the third one

Tags: python, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two pyspark dataframes using a third one. The third has information about from which of the first two DFs, data should be taken.

Dataframes (`first`, `second`, `control`):

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2034 | 12 | 444 | 100 | 200 |
| 2034 | 12 | 233 | 1633 | 2546400 |
| 3211 | 11 | 311 | 456 | 544 |
| 3113 | 13 | 441 | 333 | 645 |

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2034 | 12 | 444 | 133 | 444 |
| 2034 | 12 | 233 | 333 | 34211 |
| 3211 | 11 | 311 | 7685 | 867443 |
| 3113 | 13 | 441 | 6544 | 63457 |

| ID2 | SOURCE |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | first |
| 12 | second |
| 13 | first |

After the join, data would look like this:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2034 | 12 | 444 | 133 | 444 |
| 2034 | 12 | 233 | 333 | 34211 |
| 3211 | 11 | 311 | 456 | 544 |
| 3113 | 13 | 441 | 333 | 645 |

How can I make it? I have such a scheme, but don't know how to apply the third dataframe control.

```py
cols_list = [
             # cols with aliases to choose
            ]
            
first = first.alias("a").join(
    second.alias("b"), ((first['ID1'] == second['ID1']) & first['ID2'] == second['ID2']) & first['ID3'] == second['ID3'])), 'left'
).select(cols_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with pure Spark SQL instead of the PySpark Dataframe API, then here is one solution.

First create data frames (optional since you already have data)

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, IntegerType, StringType

core_schema = StructType([
  StructField("ID1",IntegerType()),
  StructField("ID2",IntegerType()),
  StructField("ID3",IntegerType()),
  StructField("Data1",IntegerType()),
  StructField("Data2",IntegerType()),
])

first_data = [
  (2034,    12,     444,    100,    200),
  (2034,    12,     233,    1633,   2546400),
  (3211,    11,     311,    456,    544),
  (3113,    13,     441,    333,    645),
]
second_data = [
  (2034,    12,     444,    133,    444),
  (2034,    12,     233,    333,    34211),
  (3211,    11,     311,    7685,   867443),
  (3113,    13,     441,    6544,   63457),
]

first_df = spark.createDataFrame(first_data,core_schema)
second_df = spark.createDataFrame(second_data,core_schema)

control_schema = StructType([
  StructField("ID2",IntegerType()),
  StructField("SOURCE",StringType())
])
control_data = [
  (11,  "first"),
  (12,  "second"),
  (13,  "first"),
]
control_df = spark.createDataFrame(control_data, control_schema)
display(control_df)
```

Next create temporary views for each dataframe. We need views in order to execute SQL queries. The below code creates a view called "first_tbl" from the "first_df" dataframe, etc

```py
# create views
first_df.createOrReplaceTempView("first_tbl")
second_df.createOrReplaceTempView("second_tbl")
control_df.createOrReplaceTempView("control_tbl")
```

Next we write our SQL query. The query will:

- do an inner join between first_tbl and second_tbl by all the ID
  columns
- do an inner join with control_tbl
- do a switch case statement to pick up data from correct table. For example if control_tbl.SOURCE is "first" then it picks up data from first_tbl

```sql
select 
  f.ID1, 
  f.ID2, 
  f.ID3,
  c.SOURCE,
  -- switch case statement to select data based on source
  CASE WHEN c.SOURCE == "first" then f.Data1 else s.Data1 END as Data1,
  CASE WHEN c.SOURCE == "first" then f.Data2 else s.Data2 END as Data2
  
from first_tbl f
inner join second_tbl s
  on f.ID1 = s.ID1 and f.ID2 = s.ID2 and f.ID3 = s.ID3
inner join control_tbl c
  on f.ID2 = c.ID2
```

Finally we execute the query and create a new dataframe called "final_df"

```py
query = """
select 
  f.ID1, 
  f.ID2,
  f.ID3,
  c.SOURCE,
  -- switch case statement to select data based on source
  CASE WHEN c.SOURCE == "first" then f.Data1 else s.Data1 END as Data1,
  CASE WHEN c.SOURCE == "first" then f.Data2 else s.Data2 END as Data2
  
from first_tbl f
inner join second_tbl s
  on f.ID1 = s.ID1 and f.ID2 = s.ID2 and f.ID3 = s.ID3
inner join control_tbl c
  on f.ID2 = c.ID2
"""

final_df = spark.sql(query)
final_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---+---+------+-----+-----+
| ID1|ID2|ID3|SOURCE|Data1|Data2|
+----+---+---+------+-----+-----+
|3211| 11|311| first|  456|  544|
|2034| 12|444|second|  133|  444|
|2034| 12|233|second|  333|34211|
|3113| 13|441| first|  333|  645|
+----+---+---+------+-----+-----+
```